# Как правильно вывести поле-селектор переключения статуса из админки в общую форму вывода в пользовательской части?

Tags: php, html, битрикс

Битрикс. Есть поле-селектор, в котором можно выбрать статус заявки. Привожу пример функции, которая обрабатывает выбранное значение, присваивает ему текст и выделяет цветом в админской части:

```
 function GetAdminListViewHTML($arProperty, $value, $strHTMLControlName)
{
    $html = '';
    if ($value['VALUE'] == '1'){
        $html = '<div style="background: red; color: #fff; text-align: center">
            Подготовка
        </div>';
    }elseif ($value['VALUE'] == '2'){
        $html = '<div style="background: green; color: #fff; text-align: center">
            Опубликован
        </div>';
    }elseif ($value['VALUE'] == '3'){
        $html = '<div style="background: silver; color: #000; text-align: center">
            Ожидает публикации
        </div>';
    }
    elseif ($value['VALUE'] == '4'){
        $html = '<div style="background: lawngreen; color: #fff; text-align: center">
            На рассмотрении
        </div>';
    }
    elseif ($value['VALUE'] == '5'){
        $html = '<div style="background: blue; color: #fff; text-align: center">
            Завершен
        </div>';
    }
    return $html;
}
```

Есть форма вывода общей информации о заявке в пользовательской части:

```
<div class="text-block">
        <p>Дата публикации: <strong><?= $arResult['DISPLAY_ACTIVE_FROM'] ?></strong></p>
        <p>Статус заявки: <?= $arProps['STATYS']['VALUE'] ?></p>
        <p>Дата принятия Технической части: <strong><?= $arProps['PRIT']['VALUE'] ?></strong></p>
        <? if ($arProps['PRODT']['VALUE']) { ?>
            <p> Дата продления Технической части: <strong><?= $arProps['PRODT']['VALUE'] ?></strong></p>
        <? } ?>
        <p>Дата принятия Коммерческой части: <strong><?= $arProps['PRIK']['VALUE'] ?></strong></p>
        <? if ($arProps['PRODK']['VALUE']) { ?>
            <p> Дата продления Коммерческой части: <strong><?= $arProps['PRODK']['VALUE'] ?></strong></p>
        <? } ?>
        <p>Специалист ЦВП: <strong><?= $arProps['SPEC']['VALUE'] ?></strong>,
            телефон: <?= $arProps['PHONE']['VALUE'] ?>, e-mail:
            <a href="mailto:<?= $arProps['EMAIL']['VALUE'] ?>"><?= $arProps['EMAIL']['VALUE'] ?></a></p>
    </div>
```

При выводе свойства `<p>Статус заявки: <?= $arProps['STATYS']['VALUE'] ?></p>` выводится просто значение массива равное двум, а нужно сделать так что этому значению присваивался текст и цвет. Помогите кто может.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Нужно сделать почти тоже самое:

```
<div class="text-block">
    <p>Дата публикации: <strong><?= $arResult['DISPLAY_ACTIVE_FROM'] ?></strong></p>
    <p>Статус заявки:
        <?php switch ($arProps['STATYS']['VALUE']) {
            case '1':
                echo '<span style="background: red; color: #fff; text-align: center">
                Подготовка
            </span>';
                break;
            case '2':
                echo '<span style="background: green; color: #fff; text-align: center">
                Опубликован
            </span>';
                break;
            case '3':
                echo  '<span style="background: silver; color: #000; text-align: center">
                    Ожидает публикации
                </span>';
                break;
            case '4':
                echo  '<span style="background: lawngreen; color: #fff; text-align: center">
                    На рассмотрении
                </span>';
                break;
            case '5':
                echo  '<span style="background: blue; color: #fff; text-align: center">
                    Завершен
                </span>';
                break;
        } ?>
    </p>
    <p>Дата принятия Технической части: <strong><?= $arProps['PRIT']['VALUE'] ?></strong></p>
    <? if ($arProps['PRODT']['VALUE']) { ?>
        <p> Дата продления Технической части: <strong><?= $arProps['PRODT']['VALUE'] ?></strong></p>
    <? } ?>
    <p>Дата принятия Коммерческой части: <strong><?= $arProps['PRIK']['VALUE'] ?></strong></p>
    <? if ($arProps['PRODK']['VALUE']) { ?>
        <p> Дата продления Коммерческой части: <strong><?= $arProps['PRODK']['VALUE'] ?></strong></p>
    <? } ?>
    <p>Специалист ЦВП: <strong><?= $arProps['SPEC']['VALUE'] ?></strong>,
        телефон: <?= $arProps['PHONE']['VALUE'] ?>, e-mail:
        <a href="mailto:<?= $arProps['EMAIL']['VALUE'] ?>"><?= $arProps['EMAIL']['VALUE'] ?></a></p>
</div>
```

Comment: Спасибо большое, помогло)) с php у меня туго пока))